# Change base class of existing derivated class

Tags: c++

At the moment I'm writing an application which shows level measurement data into some graphs. Always I have date/time on x-axis and data on th y-axis. I use Qwt for this and modified QwtPlotPicker class to show proper time labels. I did this by derivation and redefining a member function:

```
class myQwtPlotPicker : public QwtPlotPicker {
Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit myQwtPlotPicker( QWidget* canvas, bool DateScale = false );
  explicit myQwtPlotPicker( int xAxis, int yAxis, QWidget* canvas, bool DateScale = false );
  explicit myQwtPlotPicker( int xAxis, int yAxis, RubberBand rubberBand, DisplayMode trackerMode, QWidget* canvas, bool DateScale = false );
  virtual ~myQwtPlotPicker() {};

protected:
  virtual QwtText trackerTextF( const QPointF &position ) const {
    ... redefinition of the label text ...
  }

};
```

As you can see I also added a new parameter DateScale which turns date labels on or off. This works perfectly, but there is a class QwtPlotZommer which is derivated from QwtPlotPicker:

```
class QWT_EXPORT QwtPlotZoomer: public QwtPlotPicker { };
```

Now, the problem is, how do I get the class QwtPlotZommer to derive from myQwtPlotPicker and not from QwtPlotPicker?
Or course I could edit the Qwt sources, but there has to be a proper way of doing this.

I hope there is a proper way to do this. I would be glad, if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Why do you need to change the base class of `QwtPlotZoomer` ? What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: This is an XY problem. user2746051, try to tell us about the problem you are trying to rather than asking about your attempted solution (which can't be done).

Comment: @Synxis: the labels printed by QwtPlotPicker (floating point) don't fit for time axis. That's why I changed QwtPlotPicker. Now when using QwtPlotZoomer (which derives from QwtPlotPicker) i get the "old" labels from there, not my modified labels. So, I try to get QwtPlotZoomer derived from myQwtPlotPicker instead of the original QwtPlotPicker.

Comment: @Hulk: no, my problem is not how to set up a proper plot in QWT, I know how to do this.

Comment: @mfranke Ok, so you are trying to find a way to customize the way labels work in your plot. I don't know how to do this, but it may yield better results if you ask a new question describing what exactly how you want your plot to behave and in which way the default behavior is not acceptable for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overload QwtPlotZoomer reimplementing trackerTextF(). If you also have a use case of a standalone QwtPlotPicker - not being a QwtPlotZoomer - you have to do it twice:

class YourPicker: public QwtPlotPicker ...
class YourZoomer: public QwtPlotZoomer ...

As your implementation is a one-liner I don't see a problem in writing it twice, but if you want to avoid that, you have to put the code to some other class, that is called in both overloaded methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try multiple inheritance:

```
class myQwtPlotZoomer : public QwtPlotZoomer, public QwtPlotPicker { };
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this helps deriving from myQwtPlotPicker instead of QwtPlotPicker.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to change class hierarchy at runtime in C++.

Comment: Although this is true, the question is is not about runtime. The OP need this at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you should reconsider your design - you cannot and should not change the inheritance hierarchy of some library class.

Did you look at some examples to see how the classes you mentioned are intended to be used?  Perhaps you should ask a new question to find out how to solve the problem you are actually facing (i.e. how to create a zoomable plot in qwt if I understand you correctly)

Comment: No, the zooming works just fine on all graphs. Only the label while creating a zooming area is not what I want. The labels are floating point precision, which is not useful for date/time axis. Because there is no function for changing the lables, I tried to redefine a function.